# Netsuite Query to fetch Invoice and Related payments based on Period

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am new to Suitelet Query,

I am trying to fetch all paid invoices payment transactions for report,

The get it we need to fetch (Invoice -> Related list -> Payments)

I have fetched the Invoice but I am unable to fetch the Relatedlist of the invoice.

**My question:**
Is it possible to fetch the payment transaction for Invoice through Netsuite Suitelet Query?

What i am trying to do is archive the same data as "Custom Realized Exchange gain/Loss" Report.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

All you need to do is create a Saved Search on Invoice, include all the fields you require (by payment details, I think you are talking about the amount/GL Impact).

Once you create the Saved Search, all you need to do is load it within your script.

```
var mySearch = search.load({
 id: 'customsearch_my_so_search'
});
```

Next, you will need to run this Saved Search and store result in a variable. For this, follow

```
var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange({start:0,end:999});
```

This will get all your data in the `searchResult` variable. Now, you just need to display these on the Suitelet. For this, use for loop iterating from 0 to searchResult.length

```
for(var i=0; i<searchResult.length; i++) {
   //Print all the results 
   //Use this syntax to display all required fields

   sublist.setSublistValue({
      id:'custpage_sublist_your_id',
      line:i,
      value:''
   });
}
```

I am hoping I've solved your doubt. If you face any difficulty, please add in the comment section and I'll edit the answer as per requirement.

Comment: Hi Saish,  The payment details I mentioned is the "payment transaction" for the PAID Invoices that will be showed in Paid Invoice ->Related Records -> Payments Tab.

Comment: Hello, I understood your question now. As there are many different transactions possible to be present under "payment transaction", are you looking for any particular one (Like for example, only Credit Memos) or you want them all?